# Class without Verticle implement and event loop

Tags: asynchronous, vert.x, event-loop

I'm not sure to understand correctly the verticles principle. If my main class extends `AbstractVerticle` (implements the `Verticle` interface) and this class create instances of other class (by example, Controllers for MVC use case), the execution process of the functions in theses class is also asynchronous ? Even if theses class (controllers in my example) doesn't implements `Verticle` interface ?

I just want to have a full asynchonous execution in the same thread, i dont't want to use a worker verticle.

Thx for reading.

Comment: Can you details a bit more what you're trying to achieve ? I quite don't get your issue.

Comment: @GregoireDucharme I think it's more of a conceptual question rather than related to any desired functionality.

Comment: I think reading https://vertx.io/blog/an-introduction-to-the-vert-x-context-object/ will help your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an `object` as class variable in your class the extends `AbstractVerticle` then every method you would call with your `object` would be executed on your `Verticle` thread.

If your `object` is a synchronous class obviously this might block your thread execution.

Comment: Ok, so if i use a class Controller which doesn't extends AbstractVerticle and i call an object of this class in my Verticle, the method of this object will be executed on the verticle thread but it can block the thread execution. The solution is to extends my controller with AbstractVerticle ?

Comment: This is not true. When you deploy a verticle, an event-loop is assigned to handle its events. So let's say in your verticle you use files and an HTTP server, then all callbacks will be executed on the same thread. It doesn't matter if the code is inside the verticle class file or another class. What's important is how the object is reached. So if you create a separate class for your controller and invoke it from the verticle class, the code will be executed by the verticle thread a well. I recommend reading https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/

Comment: Ok, thx for theses answers, i just want to make the code clear to understand. But the execution must be fully asynchronous.